# Bind variables in SELECT statement

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I have tables in my Oracle database

```
PROJECTINFO
NAME       SCHEMA
--------------------------
Test       W_TEST_000

SAMPLESET 
NAME          SS_ID
--------------------------
Test_SSet     1049
```

in my SQL*Plus script a have a substitution variable (set directly or from user input)

```
DEFINE Project_Name = 'Test'
DEFINE SampleSet_Name = 'Test_SSet'
```

Now I need another two bind variables

```
VAR Project_Schema varchar2(50)
VAR SampleSet_ID number
```

Then I need to place a result of a SELECT statement into two bind vars

```
SELECT SCHEMA INTO :Project_Schema FROM PROJECTINFO WHERE NAME = '&Project_Name';
SELECT SS_ID INTO :SampleSet_ID from SAMPLESET WHERE NAME = '&SampleSet_Name';
```

Now I need to use both `:Project_Schema` and `:SampleSet_ID` in SELECT statement from `W_TEST_000.MY_TABLE` subtable like this:

```
SELECT NAME FROM :Project_Schema.MY_TABLE WHERE SS_ID = :SampleSet_ID
```

But this does not work.. (ORA-00903: invalid table name)

How to use bind variables in future SQL requests within the same SQL*Plus script?

Comment: You can use Dynamic SQL for this. Try [EXECUTE STATEMENT](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/executeimmediate_statement.htm)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it will work if you encapsulate the selects in PL/SQL blocks e.g.

```
DEFINE Project_Name = 'Test'
DEFINE SampleSet_Name = 'Test_SSet'

VAR Project_Schema varchar2(50)
VAR SampleSet_ID number


begin
  SELECT SCHEMA 
    INTO :Project_Schema 
    FROM PROJECTINFO 
   WHERE NAME = '&Project_Name';
end;
/
begin
  SELECT SS_ID 
    INTO :SampleSet_ID 
    from SAMPLESET 
   WHERE NAME = '&SampleSet_Name';
end;
/        

 --test the contents of the variable
Select :SampleSet_ID, :Project_Schema from dual;
```

Comment: However, if SAMPLESET is inside table which name is in :Project_Schema variable, how can I access it? I mean W_TEST_000.SAMPLESET, then if I type Select :Project_Schema.SAMPLESET.. it does not work.

Comment: Hi @Alexander, did this answer solve your problem? can you please mark the question as answered and mark the answer as accepted? it will help both reputations by adding us points =)

Comment: can you be more specific with what you want?
SAMPLESET is a table in your example, what do you mean with it being inside a table in project_schema?

Comment: Sorry for this confusion.. Please look at the last part of my top post - now I have to select from table `W_TEST_000.MY_TABLE` but having `W_TEST_000` in the variable `Project_Schema`. So I need to execute something like this: `SELECT NAME FROM :Project_Schema.MY_TABLE WHERE SS_ID = :SampleSet_ID`. My question is - how to correctly write this request (part after `FROM`) ?

Comment: you can either use a ref cursor or just dynamic SQL `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT NAME FROM '||:PROJECT_SCHEMA'||'.MY_TABLE WHERE SS_ID = :SampleSet_ID' INTO <my_name_var> using :SampleSet_ID`

Comment: I haven't tested the code but you should include it in another `BEGIN...END`block in your code. Also <my_name_var> should be a valid variable in your pl/sql block :)